# Textarea content change with select option onchange in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, server, onchange

This is my first question, so I'm sorry if I do something wrong.
I have a `textarea` and a select. I want to change `textarea` content that I have typed in when I change option in select. But when I change back to previous option in select I want `textarea` to show content I have previously typed.

e.g When I choose "English" option in select I want `textarea` to show "English text". Then when I choose "French" I want `textarea` to show "French text", but when I choose "English" option again, `textarea` needs to show "English text" again.

**EDIT:** I need to store data on server side, so it can be readable from any computer! Sorry for not defining it earlier.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<select class="dropdown no-border" id="dropdownLanguage">
     <option>Choose language</option>
     <option>English</option>
     <option>French</option>
 </select>

 <textarea name="agencyDescription" id="agencyDescription" class="about-agency" placeholder="Write something about your agency..." maxlength="5000">
     <?php echo $agency->getData('agencyDescription'); ?>
 </textarea>
```

@OliverRadini 's code for JS:

```
var languageDropdown = document.getElementById("dropdownLanguage");
var lastSelected = languageDropdown.options[languageDropdown.selectedIndex].value

console.log(lastSelected);

languageDropdown.onchange = function(){

    var textBox = document.getElementById("agencyDescription");    
    currentText = textBox.value;

    var selected = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;

    //load the current text into the last selected value
    sessionStorage.setItem(lastSelected, currentText);


    //load the new text in to the text box
    textBox.value = sessionStorage.getItem(selected);

    lastSelected = selected;
};
```

I would like to keep with JS instead of jQuery.
Thank you, up front!

Comment: `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` might help you out here :)

Comment: Localstorage is a good idea like @AhsN says, or you could store your english and french text in hidden elements in the markup

Comment: `localStorage` is helping, but I need a server side storage so I can access data on other devices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a fiddle I made, it works but if it's not perfect I'd appreciate the feedback:

https://jsfiddle.net/szmnforr/

```
var languageDropdown = document.getElementById("dropdownLanguage");

var lastSelected = languageDropdown.options[languageDropdown.selectedIndex].value

console.log(lastSelected);

languageDropdown.onchange = function(){

    var textBox = document.getElementById("agencyDescription");    
    currentText = textBox.value;

    var selected = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;

    //load the current text into the last selected value
    sessionStorage.setItem(lastSelected, currentText);


    //load the new text in to the text box
    textBox.value = sessionStorage.getItem(selected);

    lastSelected = selected;
};
```

It's pretty ugly, and I don't like the global variable use, but it basically works.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you very much!

Comment: I only changed from sessionStorage to localStorage so it can be persistent

Comment: Wasn't this accepted at one point? I think you should accept one of the answers here (not necessarily mine) and ask again elsewhere, otherwise it'll be confusing for anyone who comes back in the future.

Comment: Yes, I did accept it, but I edited my question (didn't want to ask a new one very similar), because I need to keep data on server side so I can access it on other devices. Nevertheless, I will accept your comment again because it was the most helpful one. If you could help me with server side storage, I would be very grateful!

Comment: Well, I would suggest asking another question - people won't be annoyed at having a similar question, I think it's better to have questions tagged appropriately. I'm happy to help where I can though - do you have any data stored on your server already?

Comment: I agree. I am working in localhost and application is working fine considering your solution. It shows up content in textarea I already typed when I open new tab or window, but when I run it in incognito mode it won't show me content I entered. So I am assuming it shoud be stored on server side.

Comment: So basically the problem is that the data is stored on the client, that is the user's machine, so it won't be reliable/persistent. So you need to store the data on a server. My recommendation is to use php. Have you worked with php before, or sql?

Comment: I have basic knowledge of php, I'm learning it currently so it would be nice if you could help me with php solution. This app is actually a Magento app, so I really don't want to work in sql with its database

Comment: As I understand it Magento is built using php, so you could potentially create a separate database on your server and store the data on a table within that database. This is not a simple question however. You may want to ask a question with the tags php, magento, sql, that is more likely to get you a good answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but i think something like that should done what you expect...

```
<select class="dropdown no-border" id="dropdownLanguage">
   <option selected="selected">Choose language</option>
   <option value="0">English</option>
   <option value="1">French</option>
</select>

<textarea name="agencyDescription" id="agencyDescription" class="about-agency" placeholder="Write something about your agency..." maxlength="5000">            
</textarea>


<script type="text/javascript">

    var select = document.getElementById("dropdownLanguage");
    var selectArray = [];
    var textArray = ["english txt","french txt"];
    var tArea = document.getElementById("agencyDescription");

    select.onclick = function(){
       textArray[parseInt(select.options[select.selectedIndex].value)]=tArea.value;
    }
    select.onchange = function(){
       tArea.value = textArray[parseInt(select.options[select.selectedIndex].value)];
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Could explain later if you want i have to move now